# postfix - how to prevent users from sending with another users name

Tags: postfix

Even though my postfix server cannot be used without authentification (open relay), sending mail in another users name after logging in is still possible like this:

```
EHLO domain.org
auth plain eW91IGxpdHRsZSBkaXJ0eSBiYXN0YXJkIDstKQ==
235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
mail from: otheruser@domain.org
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to: recipient@otherdomain.org
250 2.1.5 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Please send me your account info.
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as D40692A61AA
quit
```

How can this be prevented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
```

you should have (possibly among other things):

```
        reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch,
```

You must have `smtpd_sender_login_maps` defined to provide a username to email address mapping.

Comment: This looks very promising, thank you! I suppose it is also possible to specifically _allow_ a certain user to send using another users name? (For example, when acting as a relay host)

Comment: Yes, if you put them in the aforementioned login map.